# Hovering a div only if another div is hovered

Tags: html, css, hover, onhover

I am new to HTML and CSS. At the moment, I am trying to learn them. What I want to do is hiding a div and showing him only if you hover on another div. I almost did it, but I do not know how exactly to block the div and let only the hovered part of the div visible. (Tried with display:block; and visibility:hidden; but nothing seems to work). If someone could help me I would be really thankful. Thanks in advance.

PS: The idea is when you hover on "Menu" to hover automatically a div called "OnThisPage".

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#232323;
}

#NavigationWrap{
 position:relative;
 width:100vw;
 height:5vw;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#Logo{
 position:relative;
 margin-left:1vw;
 top:50%;
 width:29vw;
 height:4vw;
 transform:translateY(-50%);
 float:left;
}
  
#NavigationMenu{
 position:relative;
 top:50%;
 width:70vw;
 height:2vw;
 float:right;
 transform:translateY(-50%);
}

#NavigationMenu li{
 position:relative;
 top:50%;
 list-style-type: none;
 float:right;
 transform:translateY(-50%);
}
 
#NavigationMenu li:after{
 position:relative;
 margin-right:1vw;
 font-family: 'OpenSans_Bold';
 font-size:2vw;
 content:"|";
}
 
#NavigationMenu li:first-child:after{
 content:" ";
}
 
#NavigationMenu li a{
 position:relative;
 margin-right:1vw;
 font-family: 'OpenSans_Bold';
 font-size:2vw;
 color: #cc6666;
 text-decoration: none;
}
 
#NavigationMenu li a.active{
 color:#00cccc;
}
 
#NavigationMenu li a.active:hover + #OnThisPage:hover{
 color:#000000;
}
 
#NavigationMenu li a:hover{
 position:relative;
 color:#00cccc;
 -webkit-transition: all 750ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 750ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 750ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 750ms ease;
 transition: all 750ms ease;
}
  
#OnThisPage{
 position:relative;
}
 
#OnThisPage:hover{
 position:absolute;
 font-size:20vw;
 top:10vw;
 left:10vw;
 width:10vw;
 height:10vw;
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="NavigationWrap">
  <div id="Logo">Logo</div>
  <div id="NavigationMenu">
   <li><a href="#contacts">Login</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contacts">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#projects">Featured Projects</a></li>
   <li><a href="#aboue">About Me</a></li>
   <li><a class="active"  href="#home">Home</a></li>
  </div>
  <div id="OnThisPage">Test</div>
```

Comment: Are you okey about using jQuery?

Comment: Yes. However, I am not really good at jQuery. That is the first reason why I tried only with HTML and CSS.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to be as clear as possible

Comment: Thank you very much, I am really thankful. Last but not least thanks for the very detailed explanation. I am going to test it now.

Comment: You could see it live with codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQaxZj =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with jQuery, I added comments for you so you understand what you do.

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() { // we wait for document to get ready state
  jQuery("#NavigationMenu li a").hover(function() { // we get hover state event on Menu
    jQuery("#OnThisPage").toggleClass("hover") // and we just toggle class "hover" for another div
  })
})
```

Don't forget to load jQuery like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And very small change to your CSS code - it's not :hover, but .hover now

```
#OnThisPage.hover{
    position:absolute;
    font-size:20vw;
    top:10vw;
    left:10vw;
    width:10vw;
    height:10vw;
    background:red;
}
```

The idea is that we toggle class for the element when the other element is hovered and apply styles not for :hover, but for this new class.